# Association between User Owner and Guests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

User is the User of the website.
If User will create a page in the website then the user who creates the pages will become the ownwer of that particular page.
User can send invitation to other user to join his page.
If a User will join the other user's page then that user who joins the page will become the guest for that page.

So please any one help me out to design the data base for the above model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be three models one for User, other for the Website pages created by the user and the third one will be storing the details of guests visiting the pages.

Below is the high level description between user, website_page and website_guest. Please add the specifications in the database which are needed in the application.

```
User 
has_many :website_pages, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :website_guest, through: :website_pages


Website_pages   #user_id (will be the owner)
belongs_to :user
has_many: website_guests, dependent: :destroy

Website_Guests   #website_id (will reference the website page) , guest_id 
belongs_to :website_pages
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :guest_id
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

you will have 3 models: `User, Pages, Member`. The migrations would be the following:

#### Migrations

```
# Generate the model User
be rails g model user email:string
# Generate the model Page
be rails g model page title:string user:references
# Generate the model Member
be rails g model member user:references page:references
```

#### Relationships

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members
  has_many :memberships, through: :members, source: :page
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :guests, through: :members, source: :user 
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :page
end
```

#### Console

You can try to test it into the console:

```
user1 = User.create email: 'user1@test.com'
user2 = User.create email: 'user2@test.com'
user3 = User.create email: 'user3@test.com'

page1 = user1.pages.create title:'Page 1'
page1.members.create user:user2

page2 = user2.pages.create title:'Page 2'
page2.members.create user:user1
page2.members.create user:user3

page2.owner
#<User id: 2, email: "user2@test.com", created_at: "2018-05-20 11:03:10", updated_at: "2018-05-20 11:03:10">

page2.guests
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1, email: "user1@test.com",..>, #<User id: 3, email: "user3@test.com",..]>

user2.memberships
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I hope I have helped you, they are different approaches to follow, a lot depends on your business logic and domain. Rails is very flexible and well documented. I recommend you to check:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many
- https://www.sitepoint.com/master-many-to-many-associations-with-activerecord/